# Iterating and Creating date and time in C++

Tags: c++, class, date, time

I am new to c++ and I have a project in which I need to create let's say a class that would handle different operations for me.

For example i need operations like add one hour to time, I need to set my own date and some kind of update operation.

Lets say i create a class called Timer. In this class i would probably need some atributes for day, year etc.. and couple of operations which i would use in different classes. I need to have an operation called getDay in which i could get a current day in system then addOneHour where i could add one hour to the system time also i would probably need an update operation where i could update the Timer whenever I make some changes to date and time.

I tried creating something similar but I was only able to get the current time, i could not figure out how to make it work with my own atributes.

Can anyone give me any tips on how to do this ?

Comment: This should be covered in your C++ text book.

Comment: Hi and [welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please have a look at [ctime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/ctime) on cppreference.com

Comment: @Jabberwocky it is not, we have no textbook for this , they gave us really weak basics

Comment: @VincentŠin this question is too broad. You need to tell us what exactly you want do. You also need to come up with something you have done on your own. And ask questions about that. Read this: [ask]

Comment: @Jabberwocky, let me edit my post

Comment: As a first step, you need to become certain about what you're going to do – "some kind of update operation" doesn't really mean anything. Write down exactly what operations you want (naming is important) and exactly what they do. Then define a class with that interface, without implementing it. Then figure out a representation that makes those operations convenient and implement them. (Don't be afraid to change the representation if the implementation turns out difficult and vice versa.)

Comment: Try to have a look here: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date if that is not enough please get back again

Comment: Check [std::chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono)

Comment: You write: _"I tried creating something similar "_. You should show us what you have tried.